# Full brackets in Auto-Latex Equations add-on for Google Docs

Tags: equations, matrices

I am trying to create full brackets within an array, using [Auto-Latex Equations](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Commands#Other_Functions) [plugin](https://sites.google.com/site/autolatexequations/tutorial) for google docs, so I can stack elements over the top of each other. For example, in the following code I have 0 over 0 but the brackets on either side are below the 0's ([image: example]).

```
$$\dbinom{S_0}{S_\delta} \sim N \left(\begin{array}{ccc} [\begin{array}{c} 0 & 0 \end{array}] &,& \left(\begin{array}{cc} \sigma^2_S_0 & \rho_S_0,_S_\delta\sigma_S_0\sigma_S_\delta & \rho_S_\delta_,_S_0\sigma_S_0\sigma_S_\delta & \sigma^2_S_\delta \end{array}\right) \end{array}\right)$$
```

I see the commands `\lceil` and `\lfloor` but of course these brackets are only half of what I am looking for. I would ideally like to recreate something like this [image].

Comment: @AlanMunn  Kind user Kreitz Gigs, my code is written in LaTeX and I have not used word that I not like. I have written that your second image is created with Word. I see that the characters are the same. If you want a plugin-in to write in LaTeX with Google Docs you can see this plugin: https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/autolatex_equations/850293439076.

Comment: @Sebastiano That plugin is what the OP is asking about in the first place.

Comment: @AlanMunn Then have you understood that often I undestood other? :-((( What I must do? Can I delete my answer? For me no problem :-)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using the matrices? I think that the 2nd image is written with equation editor of Word with the option *Insert equation*.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{bmatrix}
Y_{1j}\\
Y_{2j}\\
\cdots\\
Y_{n_ij}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\cdots\\
1
\end{bmatrix}[\gamma_{00}]+[u_{0j}]+\begin{bmatrix}
e_{1j}\\
e_{2j}\\
\cdots\\
e_{n_ij}
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I see, so this is using LaTex in word? Do you have any resources for me to be able to learn this process? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$$ \left [ expression \right ] $$` instead of your brackets :)